# Email through smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I was trying to build a python script which could send emails via Gmail.

When I try to connect to the Gmail Server, I get an error `Errno 10013`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
gmail_message = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
gmail_message.starttls()
gmail_message.login('xyz@gmail.com','xyzpassword')
gmail_message.sendmail('xyz@gmail.com',['xyz@gmail.com'], msg.as_string())
gmail_message.quit()
```

Error:

```
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions given [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e0cc1b3e-2c63-451a-abc8-8e1e66a23287/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions)?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the port by

```
gmail_message = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
```

Comment: I got the same error, I changed the port number to 25 and still the same thing.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Maybe you are not authorized to open a socket to send email.

Comment: Do you have the Admin privilege?

Comment: You may take a look at this solution http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e0cc1b3e-2c63-451a-abc8-8e1e66a23287/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions

Comment: So if I used Ubuntu for this, it would be a lot easier?

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs because the firewall or antivirus software or that you were not authorized to do so. You can still get it working by properly configuration.  Under linux environment , the default setting are good to go.

Comment: It may be that you are not authorized to open a new socket as mentioned in this post, so it's a `windows` problem instead of a `python` one. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/573f98e3-67cb-4e2b-9d5e-6b815b5ed230/error-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions

Comment: I'm running Win7 and this works perfectly fine for me. in fact, I'm even running it on a school network where network is strict as ....

Answer (score 0):

This is code that worked for me on Win7. It's pretty much identical to yours.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
server.starttls()  
server.login(username,password)  
for comp in comps:
    msg = "Subject:CommenceSweep:Comp%s-%s\n\n" % (comp,sweep)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)  
server.quit()
```

Note: Did you correctly configure Gmail to allow SMTP?

Comment: I haven't configured Gmail, but I tried my above code in Ubuntu and it worked fine. what is the variable `comps` and `sweep`?

Comment: They're just chars. Sorry, I used this for one of my projects. They're just normal strings. msg is just a string. I'm pretty sure you need to configure Gmail though... unless you've already done it. because gmail rejects my connections without it.